# Permissions by repo in Google Container Registry

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry

Is there a way to have differing permissions for different repos within a single GCR project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a feature that we're investigating, but there isn't currently a method to do what you describe.